# Loop through column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

How can I loop through column - cells in `datagridview` and replace the values.

**Example**

I have a datagridview with Column name Currency Index(5)

I need to loop through that column and change the values of each cell. Instead of character ($) set string `Dollar` otherwise `Euro`.

Comment: If the data type is numeric and you have the DefaultCellStyle set to Currency, it should use the character for the current culture.  The data will not actually contain a `$` or anything else, it is just *displayed* that way

Comment: It is just for displaying purposes. I fill the datagridview from the sql table. There is no option to add or delete through dgv. Just to display user once its filled.

Comment: what is the datatype in the SQL table?  unless it is string *and* you saved a `$` to the DB, this is just a formatting issue with the column.

Comment: Let me make the different example of what im looking for . Imagine i have in sql table the column SEX. its stored as tiny int. 1 is for Man and 2 is for Women. Everything is fine. Just when i want to show it on datagridview i need to change the values instead of showing 1 or 2 i need to show Male or Female . 
http://pokit.org/get/?159f76d2729355b7556736e19a641a16.jpg

Comment: in *that* case you need a "code table" (sort of a DB version of Enum) to convert 1 and 2 (more typically M or F) to Male and Female.  MF or 1,2 would be keys into that table.  That is not relevant to formatting data values to the current culture.  What you may be accidentally veering towards is updating every single row which is not needed just to format a currency value.

Comment: Do you think like adding the one more table and connecting them to the current table. I thought there was a easier way for it :(

Comment: in the case of Gender, which has nothing to do with formatting currency, you just join the 2 tables and the DGV will display Male instead of 1 or M - it is **very** easy - just a SQL JOIN.  Much easier than looping thru every row just to change the display - which would be illegal with a DataSource anyway.

Comment: If the column **in your database** is a numeric type, there's no need to replace anything, as there's no '$' character stored anywhere. It is just **displayed** in the DataGridView that way, and the character displayed depends on the current culture, as Plutonix said. If you actually try to replace it, you'll get an error.

Comment: Re-Reading a few times your question, I think I begin to understand now. What you want is, if the value is say `$123.45`, you want to display `DOLLAR 123.45`; but if the value is `€67.89`, you want to display `EURO 67.89`. Am I right?

Comment: @JoshPart you are particualy right. Except you have only `$` and want to display it `DOLLAR` and if you have `€` you want to display it `EURO`  . All fields in column contains only `$` or `€` without any numbers.

Comment: If all you want is to show "Dollar" instead of "$" etc., then follow Plutonix's suggestion with an SQL Join, or less optimally as a substitution in the SQL Query.  Or even less optimally in the DataBound event of the gridview control.  The great thing about the SQL join is that if you need another currency (say, "Rubles") implementing it is as simple as adding a row to a table.

Comment: `Column name Currency` *that* makes it sound like the col is am actual numeric value column.  Rather then the symbols use something like the std abbrev USD, GBP etc, secret codes can be a pain to work with,so create a table and JOIN to it to translate to whatever longer text you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to loop through query.

Just use

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, CASE Currency WHEN '$' THEN 'DOLLAR' ELSE 'EURO' END FROM test_table
```

Comment: You're missing apostrophes on the $: `...WHEN '$' THEN...`